# Cluster Marker click event not triggering android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an android application that needs to shows markers on map, for that i am using google map with clustering feature. I have downloaded a demo sample from official developers website. It has code of showing cluster of marker, and a method for triggering click event on a particular cluster. Here is my code :

```
public class ClusteringDemoActivity extends BaseDemoActivity implements ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<MyItem> {
    private ClusterManager<MyItem> mClusterManager;
    private ArrayList<My_Lat_Lng> list = new ArrayList<My_Lat_Lng>();
    private My_Lat_Lng my_lat_lng = null;
    private GoogleMap mMap = null;

    @Override
    protected void startDemo() {
        mMap = getMap();
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(21.0000, 78.0000), 1));

        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, mMap);
        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);

        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(mClusterManager.getMarkerManager());
        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(mClusterManager.getMarkerManager());
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);


        try {
            readItems();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Problem reading list of markers.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(this);

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                LatLng latlng = marker.getPosition();

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + latlng.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    private void readItems() throws JSONException {
        //InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.radar_search);
        //List<MyItem> items = new MyItemReader().read(inputStream);
        loadArrayList();
        List<MyItem> items = new MyItemReader().read_Lat_Lng(list);
        mClusterManager.addItems(items);
    }

    private void loadArrayList() {


        my_lat_lng = new My_Lat_Lng("51.5145160", "-0.1270060");
        list.add(my_lat_lng);
        my_lat_lng = new My_Lat_Lng("51.5064490", "-0.1244260");
        list.add(my_lat_lng);
        my_lat_lng = new My_Lat_Lng("51.5097080", "-0.1200450");
        list.add(my_lat_lng);
        my_lat_lng = new My_Lat_Lng("51.5090680", "-0.1421420");
        list.add(my_lat_lng);
        my_lat_lng = new My_Lat_Lng("51.4976080", "-0.1456320");
        list.add(my_lat_lng);
        my_lat_lng = new My_Lat_Lng("51.5046150", "-0.1473780");
        list.add(my_lat_lng);
        my_lat_lng = new My_Lat_Lng("51.5077540", "-0.1378760");
        list.add(my_lat_lng);
        my_lat_lng = new My_Lat_Lng("51.5074250", "-0.1323230");
        list.add(my_lat_lng);
        my_lat_lng = new My_Lat_Lng("51.5070030", "-0.125560");
        list.add(my_lat_lng);
        my_lat_lng = new My_Lat_Lng("51.5061590", "-0.140280");
        list.add(my_lat_lng);
        my_lat_lng = new My_Lat_Lng("51.5047420", "-0.1470490");
        list.add(my_lat_lng);
        my_lat_lng = new My_Lat_Lng("51.5126760", "-0.1189760");
        list.add(my_lat_lng);
        my_lat_lng = new My_Lat_Lng("51.5108480", "-0.1208480");

        list.add(my_lat_lng);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<MyItem> cluster) {
              Toast.makeToast(getApplicationContext(),"click",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }



}
```

On debugging above code **onClusterClick** event is not triggering. I am not able to understand the reason, please provide some help.

Comment: Try taking out the call to `mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener()....` it might be intercepting the click event.

Comment: yes i am clicking on cluster

Comment: Is this the one you removed?  `mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() `

Comment: yes  i have removed the same

Comment: Where's the onCreate()? Is `startDemo()` a custom method from `BaseDemoActivity()`? Its probably better to use `getMapAsync()` since `getMap()` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I think thats because you override the `OnMarkerClickListener`. try to use only `setOnClusterClickListener` and `setOnClusterItemClickListener`.